# Is it possible to change misclassification cost in caret?

Tags: machine-learning, r

0
down vote
favorite

I have an imbalanced dataset to work with (with about 20-fold positive examples than negative). I know several solutions to deal with this type of data (under/oversampling, optimizing for AUC, etc.) but I would like to try changing the misclassification costs for the two groups. However, I cannot figure out the proper way to do this in caret. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to read more carefully: `train` has a `weights` parameter that do this.